# Props not updating when redux state change in React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, state

I am trying to implement Redux on a React Hooks project, but it doesnt seems to work good. Am I doing something wrong here?

reducer.js

```
const initialState = {
    educations: []
};

export default function home(state = initialState, action){
    switch(action.type){
        case GET_EDUCATIONS: {
            state.educations = action.payload;
            return state;
        }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

action.js

```
import * as types from '../constans/home';

export const getEducations = () => {
    return dispatch => {
        const edus = [
            {value: 1, name: 'Bachelor'},
            {value: 2, name: "Master"}
        ]

        dispatch({
            type: types.GET_EDUCATIONS,
            payload: edus
        })
    }
}
```

component

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {getEducations} from '../../redux/actions/home';

function Header({educations, getEducations}) { 
    useEffect(() => {
        getEducations(); //calling getEducations()
    }, [])

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(educations) //console educations after every change
    })

    return (
        <div className="main-header">
        </div>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        educations: state.home.educations
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        getEducations: () => { dispatch(getEducations())}
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Header);
```

And the education property in Header function is always an empty array, as in `initialState`.
While when I check on browser with `Redux Devtools`, it shows that the state contains those two object in array.
[image]

So no matter if I change the redux state or not, the properties of the component are going to stay as initialState.

Comment: Would you mind putting this into a CodeSandbox?

Comment: @ErtanHasani, see my solution below and let me know if that works for you :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In `redux`, you should avoid directly mutating the state of your reducer. Refrain from doing something like `state.reducers = blah`. In order for `redux` to know that you are trying to make an update to `state`, you need to return a completely new state object. Following these principles, your reducers will update correctly and your components will get the new data.

### Reducer.js

```
const initialState = {
    educations: []
};

export default function home(state = initialState, action){
    switch(action.type){
        case GET_EDUCATIONS: {
            return {
               ...state,
               educations: action.payload
            };
        }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

In the code above, we return a new state object. It will include everything from the existing `state`, hence `...state`, and we just update the `educations` property with the `action.payload`.

Comment: Now works great. Thank you for your explanation and solution!

Answer (score 1):

Can try with the reducer written this way :

```
const initialState = {
        educations: []
    };

export default function home(state = initialState, action){
    switch(action.type){
        case GET_EDUCATIONS: 
        return {
            ...state, educations:action.payload
        }

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you’re mutating the state in the reducer. The reducer should always return a new state object if something updated.

You could do what the answers above suggest, but i would recommend using a package like immer (https://www.npmjs.com/package/immer) or immutable.js to prevent any bugs down the line. Using the spread syntax can be dangerous if your state object has some deeply nested properties, and it’s hard to be 100% sure that you haven’t accidentally mutated something, especially as your app grows in size.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have solved this while I was getting this typed up - I decided to post it regardless, as it may be helpful.

On top of what Christopher Ngo already mentioned, the following example outlines how you can interact with your store to create new educations and then view them, in separate components..

[image: Edit modest-fermat-98s0r]

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I encounter this all the time and resolved it with CLEAR then GET/SET state.  This ensures a reset of the state call.

**Reducers.js**

```
const initialState = {
    educations: []
};

export default function home(state = initialState, action){
    switch(action.type){
        case GET_EDUCATIONS: {
            return {
               ...state,
               educations: action.payload
            };
        }
        case CLEAR_EDUCATIONS: {
            return initialState;
        }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

**Hooks.js**

```
...
const clearEducation = () => {
  dispatch({ type: CLEAR_EDUCATION });
}
   const getEducations = (payload) => {
      clearEducation(); // this clearing of the state is key fire re-render
      dispatch({ type: GET_EDUCATIONS, payload });
   };

}
```